# How to change the WooCommerce single product page style

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I change the single product page label (below pointing label)?
[image: Change Product lable]

---

How to add a solid white outline to product main image?
[image]

[website](http://www.noushasasart.com/product/neon-waterfall-council-house-print/)

Comment: For styling questions or issues, nobody can answer if you don't provide a live link to your website…

Comment: i have added the link at the bottom

http://www.noushasasart.com/product/neon-waterfall-council-house-print/

Answer (score 0):

**change the single product page label**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('main#loadintothis .summary table.variations td.label label').text('you label text here');
  });
```

> you can add a solid white outline to product main image by using this css

```
main#loadintothis ul.slides img {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: I added the first snippet in function.php, the entire page collapsed.

' $(document).ready(function(){
  $('main#loadintothis .summary table.variations td.label label').text('you label text here');
  });'

Comment: adding border works perfect, Thank you @dayan-khan

the only issue I have now is changing the label.

Comment: No didn't have to put those code in function.php file. We always put JavaScript into footer.php file. Now place this code into footer.php file. And let me know if it works.  <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('main#loadintothis .summary table.variations td.label label').text('you label text here'); }); </script>

Comment: Awesome. It works... Thank you @dayan-khan. you guys are awesome,

Comment: @Shaf No worries. Please mark the answer as correct so people know the question is solved :)